# WooCommerce Admin Only Email Hook

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, hooks

I'm using this to modify the email that is sent to our client for their records, but I don't want the same info displayed to their customer invoice.

```
add_action( "woocommerce_email_order_details", "wc_get_transaction");

function wc_get_transaction( $order ) {
    echo '<span style="color:#555;font-size:1.5em;">Transaction ID: '.get_post_meta( $order->id, "_transaction_id", true ).'</span>';

}
```

I tried this:

```
if ( ! $sent_to_admin ) {
    add_action( "woocommerce_email_order_details", "wc_get_transaction");

    function wc_get_transaction( $order ) {
        echo '<span style="color:#555;font-size:1.5em;">Transaction ID: '.get_post_meta( $order->id, "_transaction_id", true ).'</span>';

    }
}
```

Doesn't work though. I'm using this in my functions.php

**How can I get this so it only sends to the admin?**

Answer (score 0):

The hook woocommerce_email_order_details has 4 parameters which can help you to identify the correct message.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'so274215_add_transaction_id', 10, 4);

function so274215_add_transaction_id( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ){
    // decide here wether to show your transaction id
    if ( ! $sent_to_admin ) 
        echo '<span style="color:#555;font-size:1.5em;">Transaction ID: '.get_post_meta( $order->id, "_transaction_id", true ).'</span>';
}
```

As far as I remember the last parameter $email contains the name of the current message, just in case you want to go more into detail.

```
if( 'WC_Email_Customer_On_Hold_Order' == $email ) ...
```